# How to unlock SQLite database file?

Tags: java, sqlite

When I execute the below code, I get :

> "[SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)"

```java
try {
    String query = "WITH updates(ID, newvalue) AS ( SELECT TotalStock.Sl_No, TotalStock.Price * TotalStock.Preferred_Stock  FROM TotalStock ) update TotalStock SET Total_Price=  ( SELECT newvalue FROM updates WHERE TotalStock.Sl_No = ID )";
    String query_2="select Sl_No, Item_Name, Perishable, Stock, Preferred_Stock, Total_Price from TotalStock where Stock=?";
    PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);
    PreparedStatement pst_2=connection.prepareStatement(query_2);
    pst_2.setString(1, "0");
    pst.executeUpdate() ;
    ResultSet rs_2 = pst_2. executeQuery() ;
    
    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs_2));
} 
catch (Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

SQLite connection :

```java
Connection conn = null;

public static Connection dbConnector()
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/Users/aditya/Downloads/EISJ/CS/IA/DATABASE/login_cred.db");
            
        return conn;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Lock" means: Some other process is using it. The fix is to find whatever other application (could be another JVM, an SQLite command line tool, etc) and close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an instance that is using the SQlite file, Check if you are not running  a similar project instance that is making use of the Sqlite File.

Also ensure that you are not using external tools to inspect the sqlite file. That could block I/O operations too.